# is there any ways to connect to a file in the gcp cloudshell after usage exceeded?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I used the GCP cloudshell but didnt know that it had a limit to use...
I tried to start cloudshell but it says I have to wait until the limit reset.

Is there any ways to access to my files in cloudshell???
Please help me.

Comment: If you have GCP support option, ask them , they can do it.

Answer (score 0):

> **Cloud Shell inactivity:** If you do not access Cloud Shell for 120 days, your home disk will be deleted. You will receive an email notification before its deletion and simply starting a session will prevent its removal. Please consider a different solution on Google Cloud storage for sensitive data you wish to store long term.

> **Non-interactive usage:** Cloud Shell is intended for interactive use only. Non-interactive sessions will be ended automatically after a warning. Note that Cloud Shell sessions are capped at 12 hours, after which sessions are automatically terminated. You can use a new session immediately after.

> **Weekly usage:** Cloud Shell also has weekly usage limits. If you reach your usage limit, you'll need to wait until the specified time (listed under Usage Quota, found under the three dots menu icon) before you can use Cloud Shell again.

> **Restoring a session after a service limit violation:** If your session is terminated or cannot be established because you exceeded a service limit, Cloud Shell will display an error with a link to a form that allows you to appeal the limit violation. Click the feedback link and submit the form with more information about the tasks you were performing before your session was terminated.

Source: https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations